# Two elements with the same id, want to select one contained in a specific div

Tags: javascript, html

I have something like this

```
<div id='container0'>
    <input id='item0'>
</div>


<div id='container1'>
    <input id='item0'>
</div>
```

I want to select the second item0 (the one in div container1) and change it's id to item1. Best way to do this? Is there a way I can select all item0's on a page and then check their container div and make sure it matches to 'container1'?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You must not have multiple elements with the same ID. ID's must be unique. When you have more than one, the first one will be selected and the others ignored. Use a class name instead.

Comment: please change the `input id` to `class` or another tag created by you

Comment: The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document). The id attribute is most used to point to a style in a style sheet, and by JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to manipulate the element with the specific id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you haven't tagged this with jQuery - but I think it could be a solution. So what about giving every div a class, and then run an each-loop with jQuery?

```
<div id='container0' class='container'>
    <input id='item0' class='item'>
</div>


<div id='container1' class='container'>
    <input id='item0' class='item'>
</div>
```

Then I think an each loop could handle it like this:

```
$('div.container').each(function(key, value) { 
    var elmid = $("#"+key + " div.item).attr('id');
    var containerid = $(this).attr('id');

    var newelmid = elmid.replace('item','');    
    var newcontainerid = elmid.replace('container',''); 

    if(newelmid != newcontainerid)
    {
        $("#"+elmid).attr('id', 'item'+newcontainerid);
    }

});
```

Let me know if that is anyway near what you want to do :)

Answer (score 4):

Having more than one element with the same `id` [is **invalid**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute). So the correct solution here is: Fix that. (Typically using a `class` instead, but there are other options.)

That said, you *may* be able to use `querySelector` for this:

```
var elm = document.querySelector("#container1 #item0");
```

But as the structure is invalid, results would vary from implementation to implementation, and I wouldn't be surprised if many (or even most) returned `null`.

Again with the caveat that the real solution is to fix the invalid duplicate `id`, it may be more reliable than the above to use `getElementById` to get the `container1` element and then loop through its child nodes looking for one with `id == "item0"`.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same `id` attribute on two elements is a syntax error, so you should fix the markup. Browser behavior is undefined when the rule is violated.

If you cannot fix the error, for some odd reason, you can still find the element with `id=container1`, if that `id` attribute is unique, and then select its first child element, if the markup is exactly as given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As the others mentioned, you cannot have the same id for multiple elements.  You can, however, have the same name.  After you correct the syntax issue of multiple ids to make each if unique, you can select the second input element based on the container it is in.  I would use jQuery for this.

For example (please note that I am not at my computer - I'm on my phone, so there may be some slight syntax changes required):

```
$("#container1 > input[name='item']").attr('id', 'item1')
```

For jQuery selectors, look here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

For changing attributes, look here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/